# How to monitor network api calls on android app

Tags: wireshark, android

Hey I am trying to find a way where I can see the post request made by android app just to test all the security of an APP for that there are severl so called solutions like wireshark burp. But I don't know which one I should use I tried wireshark but my app is on my phone and I don't know how to setup wireshark to capture api post request with payload. On web browser in chrome I can inspect element and see network request. I want to know is there any way by which I can do the same for android my device is rooted any app. Wireshark and other tools are hard to configure for wlan traffic. There are many solution for this it is not hacking I just want to debug app.

Answer (score 1):

Load the Android SDK and you will find a wealth of monitoring and debugging tools.  There is also an app that you may find helpful: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en

Comment: can I do this inside geny or virtualbox

Comment: Probably so, most Android code is Java based and should work in a virtual environment.